# Windows installer with both per-user and admin parts

Tags: installation, windows-installer, uac

Is is possible to build a MSI installer which can do a per-user install for a non-admin user (copy files to the non-admin user's directories) but also copy files into Program Files or other admin-only directories? With NSIS there exists a UAC plugin that allows some steps to be run as the normal user and others to run with elevated privileges. Does such a thing exist for MSI or is there some way to retain the original user context while gaining the admin permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The installation either runs in user context or in elevated system context.

Yet it does not prevent you from copying some files into user's profile. These files will inherit the default permissions set on folders. The defaults are full access to the user, system and administrators group.

---

Although it's technically possible, I would not recommend using it. Consider a computer with several users: one of them installs your MSI package, and they get files installed in user's profile. Another user logs on this computer and starts your application from Start menu: there are no files in user's profile whereas your application expects them there.

The best approach to overcome this problem is to install the files that you want to go into user's profile to Program Files. At the first start of your application, it copies these files to user's profile. Thus every user of a multi-user computer will be able to use your application.

If these data are to be shared between users, consider installing them into ProgramData, [`CommonAppDataFolder` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367992.aspx). This way the files will be visible and readable to all users of computer. Yet only the user who installed the application will have write access, so your installer should modify permissions on your application folder inside ProgramData to give write rights to other users.

Comment: Agree with the answer: copy files per machine with the installer, then have the app copy them to the user profile on first launch. Then set a flag in HKCU to indicate that the copy operation has been done for that user.

However, it's a bit inaccurate to say that the installer runs in user context or in elevated system context - it actually runs in both contexts, but at different times in the installation sequence. In simplified terms the GUI runs in user context, whilst the file copy runs with elevated rights. I can add a longer explanation as a separate answer if need be. Out of space here

Comment: @Glytzhkof I meant that installation process (copying files, writing registry entries) is run either in the current user context, in a per-user installation, or in elevated system context, in per-machine installation. The GUI wizard is always run in current user context.

Comment: The problem with your suggestions and the reason that I'm trying to do what I've described is that the file in question MUST go in a user's appdata directory (it's a MS Word global template and Word looks in the user's STARTUP directory for these).

Comment: @idontwanttortfm But nothing stops you from putting your Word template into user's profile even when installation runs elevated. You should use [`AppDataFolder` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367565.aspx) to refer to user's profile in installation template, and add `Microsoft\Templates`. Pay attention to the fact that it would be installed *only to the current user*, other users of the computer won't have your template file. The shared location for Office template files is in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\1033`. The number `1033` is Windows Locale ID.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I think the issue is that the installer runs as an admin user rather than as the non-admin user, so the template goes in the wrong user's AppDataFolder.

Comment: @idontwanttortfm No, it's not possible unless if you use a custom action to install Word template. If you use `AppDataFolder` as a reference to folder it will be resolved to a value before the actual installation script which copies the files is run. To shed a light on what's happening, run your installation with verbose logs. The log will have the resolved locations for the files, and there will be entries when a property is assigned a new value.

Comment: See [windows guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt674655(v=vs.85).aspx) (Section 10).